# URLSession POST request with json "_id" element with codable class in Swift

Tags: swift, decodable, urlsession

I'm trying to use URLSessions to get and post data. I don't have problems with get requests on Swift, just post. [I followed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201926/post-json-request-in-swift) 
I have a codable class that looks like this:

```
class Item: Codable {
  var _id: String?
  var name: String = ""
  var color: String = ""
  var rating: Int = 0

  init(name: String, color: String, rating: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.rating = rating
  }

}
```

And json data that looks like this:

```
[ {
   "_id" : "5e50a10c4ea5d87f0001c9da",
   "name" : "Pepper",
   "color" : "blue",
   "rating" : 4
  },
  {
   "_id" : "5e50a10c4ea5d87f0001c9db",
   "name" : "Pepper",
   "color" : "blue",
   "rating" : 2
  },
  {
   "_id" : "5e50a10c4ea5d87f0001c9dc",
   "name" : "Pepper"
   "color" : "blue"
   "rating" : 6
  }
]
```

I'm currently using restdb.io for my database, and have tested my requests using Postman for all Get,Post,Put,...etc. 
On Postman, when I create a POST request with Json body with just name, color and rating elements, it will generate a unique _id without me having to specify.

When I do this on Swift and send a post request with Item object using the init() method, where I left _id as an optional in the class, my code crashes with an "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". How do I work around that?

Comment: Without looking at your code I would guess that your JSON data has a nil value for one of your other fields (name, color, or rating). Use Postman to take a peek at your response to make sure all of your required fields are present.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `_id` in your swift code you can ignore it and not include it in your codable struct. In this way, the codable will ignore it and not process it